# Memento Example From Catel

Tags: tags, catel

Hopefully this won't be such a generic question but it involves the memento example provided by Catel Examples on Github.

For some reason the MainWindow doesn't have its data context set to MainWindowViewModel. The example itself isn't functioning. I've shown the log before but some of the messages are confusing to me(lack of understanding I guess). Help is appreciated.

```
09:21:00:182 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.ServiceLocator] Registered type 'Catel.MVVM.IViewModelFactory' to instance of type 'Catel.MVVM.ViewModelFactory'
09:21:00:182 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.Providers.LogicBase] Using IViewModelFactory 'Catel.MVVM.ViewModelFactory' to instantiate the view model
09:21:00:183 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] Creating instance of type 'MomentoProject.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel' using specific parameters. No constructor found in the cache, so searching for the right one
'MomentoProject.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: MomentoProject.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Haytham\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Catel\Catel2\App2\output\Debug\Catel.Extensions.Memento.dll'. Symbols loaded.
09:21:00:191 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] Checking if constructor 'public ctor(IUIVisualizerService uiVisualizerService, IMessageService messageService, IMementoService mementoService)' can be used
09:21:00:191 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] Constructor is not valid because parameter 'mementoService' cannot be resolved from the dependency resolver
09:21:00:192 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] The constructor is valid and can be used
09:21:00:192 => [DEBUG] [Catel.IoC.TypeFactory] No constructor could be used, cannot construct type 'MomentoProject.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel' with the specified parameters
09:21:00:193 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.ViewModelFactory] Could not construct view model 'MomentoProject.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel' using injection of data context 'null'
09:21:00:193 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.Providers.LogicBase] Used IViewModelFactory to instantiate view model, the factory did NOT return a valid view model
09:21:00:195 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.Views.ViewToViewModelMappingHelper] Initializing view model container to manage ViewToViewModel mappings
09:21:00:216 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.Views.ViewToViewModelMappingHelper] Initializing view model 'null'
09:21:00:217 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.Views.ViewToViewModelMappingHelper] Initialized view model 'null'
09:21:00:217 => [DEBUG] [Catel.MVVM.Views.ViewToViewModelMappingHelper] Initialized view model container
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the memento service is not yet registered. This is because you are probably only using the interface. An interface is not a reason for .NET to load an assembly.

There are a few things to solve this:

1. Use [Fody.LoadAssembliesOnStartup](https://github.com/Fody/LoadAssembliesOnStartup)
2. Add a typeof(MementoService) at startup (so .NET will load the assembly)

You can of course also create a PR that solves this issue to help out the others using the examples as well.

Comment: Yup that fixed it. IServiceLocator serviceLocator = ServiceLocator.Default;
            serviceLocator.RegisterType<IMementoService,MementoService>();

Comment: Here do I create a PR? Thank you much by the way.

Comment: Not here, search the internet on how to do a PR (pull request)